# What does" my looks" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning

I am reading the book " A higher loyalty" by James Comey. One of the chapter describes how he was taunted in the school. I am not sure what exactly he meant saying the following " One of my first days on the fifth-grade playground, I was surrounded by a group of boys who taunted me and my looks". My looks in the dictionary appears to be - appearance , better suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your understanding - "looks" is often used to describe someone's physical appearance.

The only thing that makes your example sentence a little odd is that it says:

> ...a group of boys who taunted me **and** my looks.

It doesn't seem gramatically correct to me because your appearance is something abstract, so how can *it* be taunted?

If I was writing this sentence I would have said:

> ...a group of boys who taunted me **for** my looks.

**or**

> ...a group of boys who **mocked** me and my looks.

("Mock" means to ridicule, or laugh at, and you can laugh at the way someone looks; but "taunt" means to incite anger, to persecute, or provoke - and your looks are not going to get angry)

Comment: it is copy/paste from the book :)

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby Books can be wrong! Just my opinion. I just added a bit more info to back that thought up.

Comment: thanks, it helps me a lot ! Will come back soo. with more questions :)